# How can we redirect the page to another page when Xampp shutdown

Tags: php, xampp

How can we redirect to another webpage when the Xampp is not working in (Joomla), for example if the orginal link was

http://localhost:8010/Example

if this site isnot working, i want to redirect to another page

http://localhost/Example2

how this will possible , in Xampp ,

*Note: it is not only a single page inside the web-folder. the full folder need to change to another web address.

Answer (score 1):

When the server is not working it is NOT able to respond and you cannot redirect to another server. For that you'd need to use a third server that checks availability of the other 2 "real" servers and redirects you to one of these. (proxy-like)